# how to do a join in MySQL with a select?

Tags: php, mysql, join

i have this situation

a selecy:

```
SELECT search.id FROM database.search
WHERE search.talentnum > '0' 
AND (search.sex ='Female')
```

and i need to JOIN it with another table `database.email` based on `id`

right now i am creating a table with the first select 'CREATE TABLE database.sms (UNIQUE(id)) select...' and then i join it with the `database.email` on `id`:

```
SELECT s.id, c.fname, c.lname
FROM database.sms s, database.email c
WHERE s.id= c.id AND c.sms_ok='1'";
```

any ideas how to do this without creating an table, just a join on the main select with the second one. ?

hope i'm not too confusing

thanks

Comment: you'll need to show us the full schema of the tables involved (or at least the relevant columns)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT s.id, c.fname, c.lname
FROM search s
JOIN email c ON c.id=s.id
WHERE s.talentnum > 0
AND s.sex='Female'
AND c.sms_ok='1'
```